What I eat in a day vs what I ate in a day
So recently a trend is going on social media " what I eat in a day " videos. But what confused me is shouldn't it be what I ate in a day because what I eat in a day implies what that person eats everyday and what I ate in a day will imply what they on that specific day or I am wrong?

Yes, if these videos show everything the person has eaten during a day which is now over, they should be entitled "What I ate in a day".

eat is present tense, but regardless of how it's pronounced, ate is past tense, as any dictionary will tell you.

No, a video like that can show what is usual or habitual. What I eat in a day would not feed a chicken. It's up to the poster to decide on which tense to use. Please look up the use of the simple present.

The pretension of these videos is to show what they eat in a typical day by choosing a day at random.

@Lambie can please elaborate a bit?

"What I eat in a day" is a general statement. Look up the use of the present simple. :)

It is meant to be a sample day or on a normal day So present tense is proper. If you are talking about a particular day or a special day you can use past tense (ate). The sentence would be, "What I ate today or on Sunday."

I think there are several factors working together to make it present tense.

The strongest reason, as TimR covered, is that "day" is a clue here. These videos are a sort of "Day in the life" journalism: there are many stories, articles, videos, etc. that focus on the specific details of a single day with the premise that they can help show the general patterns of all days. By this scheme, the title could be understood as "What I eat in a [typical] day." Even if they upload many such videos, or even if one such day is very non-typical, this subtext is understood. And we use present tense for general, ongoing patterns of behavior ("What do you do for a living?").
Another is the convention of giving newspaper headlines in the present tense, even though they cover past actions. This title is like a headline, summarizing what the Youtuber reports.
Another is a sort of "narrative present tense." Yes, by the time you watch it, and even by the time they upload the video, the food has "been eaten," in the past. But while the camera is rolling, they're in the present. And a single day is a narrow enough time frame that "the present" can be stretched to include it, and the title matches the content.


You are correct in regard to the difference between "What I eat in a day" and "What I ate in a day".  But I suspect you are wrong in believing that the blog video would be about a particular day rather than what the person eats per day on a regular basis.
If it were about a particular day, it wouldn't be titled "in a day" but "on (a particular day)".

What I ate on Independence Day.
What we ate on The Feast of All Fools.
What I ate on New Year's Day.


But like , some influencers start 'what I eat in a day ' series in which they show us what they are eating on that day and like suppose they are doing it for a week and then they eat different things everyday and not just cereal for breakfast everyday .that's why I got a bit confused and since English is not my first language I was not sure about it. Can you clarify a bit more on what you were saying if it's not an issue

The preposition we would use to describe what was eaten on a particular  day is the preposition on, not the preposition in.  "on Independence Day" refers to the day as an occasion; "in a day" refers to the day as a span of time.  "What I eat in a day" could be paraphrased as "what I eat over the course of 24 hours" (or 16 hours, setting aside 8 hours for sleep).
